# Xcode: frame.size.height change makes view's height change in the downward direction?

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, height

I'm trying to have a bar that fluctuates with the mic level, but am having trouble getting it to fluctuate in the upwards direction. Here's the code

```
- (void)setVUMeterHeight:(float)height {
     if (height < 0)
        height = 0;

     CGRect frame = vuMeter.frame;
     frame.size.height = height+10;
     vuMeter.frame = frame;
}

- (void)updateVUMeter {
float height = (90+voiceSearch.audioLevel)*5/2;

     [self setVUMeterHeight:height];    
     [self performSelector:@selector(updateVUMeter) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];
}
```

The problem is the height starts at 10px, and when the mic becomes active, the height is extended, but in the downward direction.  I tried to fix this by giving the view negative height values, but views can't have negative heights.  Does anyone have an idea for how to get the height to change in the upward direction?  Thanks.

Comment: I tried looking at the Origin options for the view, but the height is still being added to the bottom instead of the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the origin upwards by the same amount you extend the size.

Something like:

```
- (void)setVUMeterHeight:(float)height {
     if (height < 0)
        height = 0;

     const CGFloat kMeterBottom = 200;
     CGRect frame = vuMeter.frame;
     frame.size.height = height+10;
     frame.origin.y = kMeterBottom - frame.size.height;
     vuMeter.frame = frame;
}
```